# how to post XML to URL in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am trying to post a string (xml) to an url

EXEC @nval = sp_OAMethod @bj, 'send', NULL, @myString

where I have declared @mystring as

declare @mystring varchar(8000)

and I am trying to create @mystring using data from a table at runtime where the @mystring value will exceed more than 8000 character and the string is truncating after character limit.

Is there anyway where I can post the large file content either by storing the content in a variable or posting the file itself fetching from some location?

I am doing this in sql server 2000.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot go beyond 8000 characters in a VARCHAR on SQL Server 2000. Try using TEXT as your data type, it is not length-limited. Please add more detail how your data transmission works, exactly.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply.

 I tried to declare a varable like

declare @nstring TEXT 

but its throwing error 

"The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables."